# Translation of medical Latin from 1839

Tags: latin-to-english-translation, medicine, paleography

I am looking at a medical journal from Frederiks Hospital in Denmark, dated November 18, 1839, and would like help with the translation.

Transcription may not be 100% correct, so I have also attached an image below (thanks to **marquinho** for corrections).

> **Constit.** obesa, robusta, aliquan-
> tum cachectica. Statura: parva.
>
> **Causa:** labor intensus, per VI menses
> protractus in molario papyro, dum
> continuo fere aqua humectarentur
> pedes.
>
> **Mb. prægr.** Anno ætatis VII<sup>mo</sup> coxalgia
> sinistra laboravit, unde jam, capiti fe-
> moris pone & supra acetabulum fixo,
> restat anchylosis. Extremitas inferior si-
> nistra debilior & magis marcida, ac alte-
> ra, invenitur.
>
> Per XXIV annos hernia inguinali dextra,
> ex entero - epiploocele formata, nunquam
> bracheris retenta, laborat æger. Nullus
> testis in scroto sinistro adest; refert æger,
> cum interdum descendere, herniamque in-
> terdum sponte recedere — quod vero haud si-
> multaneo fit.

[image]

I have pieced some of it together, but would like an accurate translation.

> **Constitution:** fat, robust, somewhat sickly [or consumptive?]. Stature: small
> **Cause:** intensive labor, has worked for 6 months in a paper mill, where he was almost constantly standing in the water.
> **Prior illnesses:** Has been plagued by hip pain in the left side since age 7, following from the femur-head being fixed above the cup, [with lasting stiffness?]. The lower left extremity has become weakened & [and here I give up...]

My mother was a pediatric nurse, and has suggested [Legg–Calvé–Perthes disease](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legg%E2%80%93Calv%C3%A9%E2%80%93Perthes_disease).

Answer (score 2):

Some tips for the palaeographic part. By and large, your transcription is accurate, but I'd correct the following:

l. 2: *cachectica*

l. 3: labor *intensus*

l. 6: *pedes* (in the paper mill, he was almost constantly standing in the water)

l. 11-12: *magis marcida, ac altera,* (the lower left extremity is weaker, more rotten(?) than the other)

l. 14: *epiploocele* ("epiplocele" with a single -o- appears standard, but compare the Greek ἐπίπλοον)

l. 16: in *scroto sinistro* (no testicle is present in the left scrotum)

l. 18-19: *simultaneo* (at the same time)

Comment: I'm making this a CW, as I feel this was too much material for a comment, but I can contribute too little in the way of translation to write up my own answer. Especially as I don't have a medical background. Hopefully others can pick it up from here!

Comment: thank you, I have incorporated the corrections into the transcription :)